# Apache Camel and Blueprint, how to hit a route within another bundle?

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I'm working with Apache Camel for the first time and I am really enjoying it.

My question is, I want to hit a route that exists in a different bundle. I'm wondering how exactly this is possible.

I have called (from my service) the invocation that hits the camel route. Within that route *calls* a URL. The URL is another route that is something like.. direct://

I'm getting the following:

```
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://
```

I was doing something like this:

```
<bean id="myBeanID" class="ClassWhereRouteIsDefined"/>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct://fromURL" />
        <to uri="direct://toURL" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Make sure that the **body's class** you are exchanging can be seen by both bundles (e.g. exported from a third bundle, or java standard classes)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. I am going to list a couple it would be impossible to list all the ways you can do this.

1. The direct-vm component provides direct, ***synchronous*** invocation of
   any consumers in a JVM instance.This endpoint can be used to connect
   existing routes in the ***same camel context***, as well from ***other
   camel contexts in the same JVM***.
2. The vm component provides ***asynchronous*** invocation of
   any consumers in a JVM instance. It is similiar to the seda component with the difference that is can ***communicate between camel contexts***. However like above they must all be in the ***same JVM***.

So if your bundles are all running on the same jvm direct-vm and vm components are the ones you can use.

To deal with bundles running on different VM's you can use a multitude of components like the list below:

- Send JMS messages to bundles. Use JMS to transport the exchange to the other side.
- When using SOAP you can transform the XML with XSLT and send across to another bundle who hosts a web-service. Using CXF to transport the exchange across.
- Using REST services. Let you bundles listen and respond to JSON objects.
- MQTT can also be used. WHich can be usefull when dealing with Camel bundles running on a Raspberry pie.

The main idea with inter server bundle communication is that you can create bundles that listen to a protocol and transform the exchange and headers to that protocol and then move on.

Comment: Do you have a good code example? 

For example, bundle 1 does a lookup to grab what route to hit dynamically. Let's say it returns direct://routeX. I am calling .toD(routeX), but unsure how to expose route X in my other bundle. I assume it needs to somehow be exposed under the same camel context, but it's in a different bundle? Edit: This might work since it's under the same JVM, though?

Comment: If the route you are calling is `.toD(direct://routeX)` you are using the direct component. This will only allow you to call the route in the same camel-context and that route will start with `from(direct://routeX)`. Try using direct-vm or vm like `.toD(direct-vm://routeX)` and start the route in another camel context with `from(direct-vm://routeX)`. Direct will not work in this case. Try styart with direct and seda and one camel-context then replace them with direct-vm and vm.

Comment: @JohnLippson you cannot share a  camel context across bundles.

Comment: Sweet. Trying direct-vm now

Comment: btw, is just calling from(...).bean(this, "mymethod") sufficient for starting up a route within another context and then just creating a bean that route exists in within blueprint? Running camel:endpoint-list doesn't show my routeX being registered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176605/discussion-between-namphibian-and-john-lippson).